# Changing the keys of a nested object in an Array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I need to change the keys of my object. I could use the map function to change the keys of my outer object. Question is, how can I access the inner object which is in an array as well. In the code below, I need to change the `team` key to `teamName`. My structure has to be in the same order.

```js
let myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
    Organization: [{ team: "value1" }, { location: "value2" }],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "foo",
    Organization: [{ team: "value1" }, { location: "value2" }],
  },
];
```

I can change the keys of the outer array like this if I want to change `id` to `userId`.

```js
const newArray = myArray.map((item) => {
  return {
    userId: item.id,
  };
});
```

But trying to change the keys in the inner list of objects for `Organization` becomes a problem. What is the best way to modify the inner keys?

Comment: What have you tried?  What happens when you try it?

Comment: There's no difference between an "inner" and "outer" array. Array is array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1 - lodash [mapKeys](https://lodash.com/docs/#mapKeys)

```js
import { mapKeys } from 'lodash';

const newArray = myArray.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  Organization: item.Organization.map(org =>
    mapKeys(org, (_, key) => (key === 'team' ? 'teamName' : key))
  ),
}));
```

#### Option 2 - object destruction

You can destruct each `Organization` and reconstruct it with `teamName`, as long as `team` exists.

```js
const newArray = myArray.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  Organization: item.Organization.map(({ team, ...rest }) =>
    Object.assign(rest, team ? { teamName: team } : {})
  ),
}));
```

---

#### Result

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
    Organization: [{ teamName: 'value1' }, { location: 'value2' }],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'foo',
    Organization: [{ teamName: 'value1' }, { location: 'value2' }],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Organization` is always an array with 2 elements. Where the first element is an object with the property `team`, and the second element is an object with the property `location`. Then the following code does job.

```js
let myArray = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo",
  "Organization": [{"team": "value1"}, {"location": "value2"}]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "foo",
  "Organization": [{"team": "value1"}, {"location": "value2"}]
}];

const result = myArray.map((item) => {
  const [{ team: teamName }, location] = item.Organization;
  return { ...item, Organization: [{ teamName }, location] };
});

console.log(result);
```

This answer makes use of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). If you don't know what this is I would highly suggest checking out the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't make it more simpler.

```js
console.log(
  [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "foo",
      "Organization": [{
        "team": "value1"
      }, {
        "location": "value2"
      }]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "foo",
      "Organization": [{
        "team": "value1"
      }, {
        "location": "value2"
      }]
    },
  ].reduce((a, b) => {
    b.Organization[0] = {
      teamName: b.Organization[0].team
    }
    a.push(b)
    return a
  }, [])
)
```